# послать GET-запрос если размеры окна браузера изменились до заданного размера

Tags: jquery

Каким образом определить что пользователь "Свернул в окно" браузер и, если размер окна в пределах `100 — 999px`, послать GET-запрос серверу?

```
$(window).resize(function()
{
    $.get("page.php", {resize: "true"});
});
```

Заметил что при работе в `WebKit` запрос посылается при малейшем изменении размеров окна.
Запрос должен отправляться единожды, если размер окна изменяется в пределах `100 — 999px` и только если размер окна превысит `999px`, а затем обратно вернется в зону `100 — 999px` - запрос отправляется вновь.

Comment: Вы не понимаете как определить что окно было больше и вот оно стало меньше? или не знаете как определить размер окна?

Comment: @Vartlok, да вы правы, мне удалось найти пример использования `resize()` и вставить внутрь GET-запрос, как его передать мне известно из ранее заданных вопросов на стеке. В остальном я еще плохо ориентируюсь в jQuery.

Comment: Т.е. у вас проблема и с определением размера и с запоминанием его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы определить размер окна надо использовать: `$(window).width()` или `$(window).height()` в зависимости от того, какой параметр вам надо контролировать, или вообще оба.

Так же, вам надо где-то хранить прошлый размер окна и был ли уже отправлен запрос, чтобы не долбить запросами на каждое изменение, когда окно уже в нужных вам размерах. Где лучше хранить в вашем случае я сказать не могу, т.к. не знаю структуры проекта и принятых практик. Можно например так:

```
var state = {};
$(window).resize(function()
{
    if ($(window).width() >= 100 && $(window).width() <= 999 && state["width"] >= 1000 && state["isSent"] != true) {
        state["isSent"] = true;
        $.get("page.php", {resize: "true"}, function( data ) {          
            state["isSent"] = false;
        });
    }
    state["width"] = $(window).width();
});
```

Comment: А какие варианты хранения данных возможны, кроме cookies? В сессионную переменную, к примеру, но тут потребуется GET-запрос к PHP скрипту чтобы сохранить данные.

Comment: @Plush я бы подумал про глобальный объект, где можно это всё сохранять. Но глобальные объекты не очень хорошо, лучше создайте объект перед назначение слушателя на эвент и туда всё сохраняйте.

Comment: Я начинаю уже понимать. Получается так. Каждый раз при изменении размера окна браузера `$(window).resize()` я проверяю текущую ширину `$(window).width()` основываясь на текущих данных и уже сохраненных делаю вывод отправлять ли GET-запрос.  Вы можете привести пример работы с `объект перед назначение слушателя на эвент` для сохранения данных?

Comment: @Plush посмотрите в ответе, надеюсь я не накосячил нигде)

Comment: Добавил условие в ваш пример. Почему-то не срабатывает `state["isSent"] != true`, то есть если запрос был уже отправлен, то не отправлять повторно. Как это проверить правильно?

Comment: @Plush поправил, попробуйте подебажить. Я же только концепцию предложил, а не 100% рабочий код.

Comment: Хочу уточнить: если get-запрос выполнен успешно, ставится `state["isSent"] = false;` — то есть метка, что запрос был выполнен. А для чего используется `state["isSent"] = true;` перед get-запросом?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34593/discussion-between-vartlok-and-plush).